# How to create custom gridview as shown in image

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-drawable

I am a newbie to android programming, have learnt the basics.

Now, I want to create a view as shown in below link through java side and not through xml.

[Example 2X2 Square Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOEyE.png)

I can use buttons or images to display such an image in xml.

But, I want in dynamically through java side, so I am not sure what to refer to get this done through java side.

Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: So you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: So your question is how to set up a grid from Java code? Or make the squares(grid elements) from Java code?

Comment: @S Praveen Kumar Yes, and after this I'll try to dynamically increase the size of grid on clicking any sqaure in grid.

Need to have random colors of grid squares also.

@Akshay These are my initial plans, I am here to take some guidance. I don't want anyone to write the code for me.

Comment: @Nik you should post your code or what have you tried until now for people to help you

Answer (score 0):

Use Recyclerview (LayoutManager is grid)

```
  GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
        recylerview.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `gridview` in your `view.xml` like below:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="16dp" />
```

after that you can create a `customAdapter` of your choice to do anything you want like below :

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public GridAdapter() {
    //constructor for your adapter
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return chargeProduct.getProducts().size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return item;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return id;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(mContext);

        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_view, null);

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }
    //Create view items and do the things you want here

    return gridView;
}
```

you also need to create `grid_item_view` layout for each of the grid items and it can be any layout you want it to be.
and at last you need to connect your view to your adapter with these to lines :

```
gridAdapter = new GridAdapter();
customGridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
```

also you can refer to these tutorials on how to start creating a **GridView**:

1.[tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm%0A)

2.[getting started on gridview](https://www.raywenderlich.com/127544/android-gridview-getting-started)

and for creating **custom adapter** for your **GridView** you can refer to this:

[creating a custom adapter for gridview](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/)

hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16396076)

Comment: tnx for the note , i edited my post so it looks better now :) @Shiro

Answer (score 0):

```
      List<Strings> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
      GridLayoutManager gLayout = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);
      RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
      rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
      rView.setLayoutManager(gLayout);
```

For more refer [here](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/)